# Nintendo 3DS YouTube Embed Support?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, nintendo-ds

Does the browser built into the Nintendo 3DS (and perhaps the 2DS) provide support for embedded YouTube iframes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those browsers might support iframes, but they don't support Flash or HTML5 video, so youTube videos will not play in the browser. The only option is the dedicated YouTube app available in the Nintendo eShop.

Answer (score 0):

The new 3DS has a vastly improved (webkit based) browser, that does support HTML5 video, so it can play YouTube (and Vimeo, etc) anywhere it's embedded